Aligning two point clouds using ICP algorithm
I have attempted to use the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm with the open3d library in Python. However, the merging result was not as expected—the second point cloud simply overlapped onto the first one without proper alignment.
Here is the Python code I used:
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

def load_point_clouds(ply_files):
    pcds = []
    for file in ply_files:
        pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file)
        pcd.estimate_normals(search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))
        pcds.append(pcd)
    return pcds

def pairwise_registration(source, target):
    print("Apply point-to-point ICP")
    icp_coarse = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        source, target, 0.1, np.identity(4),
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint())
    icp_fine = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        source, target, 0.05, icp_coarse.transformation,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint())

    print("Apply point-to-plane ICP")
    icp_coarse = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        source, target, 0.1, icp_fine.transformation,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane())
    icp_fine = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        source, target, 0.05, icp_coarse.transformation,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane())

    transformation_icp = icp_fine.transformation
    information_icp = o3d.pipelines.registration.get_information_matrix_from_point_clouds(
        source, target, 0.05, icp_fine.transformation)
    return transformation_icp, information_icp

def full_registration(pcds):
    pose_graph = o3d.pipelines.registration.PoseGraph()
    odometry = np.identity(4)
    pose_graph.nodes.append(o3d.pipelines.registration.PoseGraphNode(odometry))

    for target_id in range(1, len(pcds)):
        transformation_icp, information_icp = pairwise_registration(pcds[0], pcds[target_id])
        odometry = np.dot(transformation_icp, odometry)
        pose_graph.nodes.append(o3d.pipelines.registration.PoseGraphNode(np.linalg.inv(odometry)))
        pose_graph.edges.append(o3d.pipelines.registration.PoseGraphEdge(0, target_id,
                                                                        transformation_icp,                   information_icp,
                                                                        uncertain=False))
    return pose_graph

    def merge_point_clouds(ply_files):
    pcds = load_point_clouds(ply_files)

    print("Full registration ...")
    pose_graph = full_registration(pcds)

    print("Optimizing PoseGraph ...")
    option =     o3d.pipelines.registration.GlobalOptimizationOption(max_correspondence_distance=0.05,
                                                                edge_prune_threshold=0.25,
                                                                reference_node=0)
    o3d.pipelines.registration.global_optimization(pose_graph,
                                                    o3d.pipelines.registration.GlobalOptimizationLevenbergMarquardt(),
                                                    o3d.pipelines.registration.GlobalOptimizationConvergenceCriteria(),
                                                option)

print("Transform points and display")
for point_id in range(len(pcds)):
    print(pose_graph.nodes[point_id].pose)
    pcds[point_id].transform(pose_graph.nodes[point_id].pose)

# Rotate the second point cloud by 180 degrees around the Z axis
'''rotation_matrix = np.array([[ -1,  0,  0,  0],
                            [  0, -1,  0,  0],
                            [  0,  0,  1,  0],
                            [  0,  0,  0,  1]])
pcds[1].transform(rotation_matrix)'''

pcd_combined = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
for pcd in pcds:
    pcd_combined += pcd
pcd_combined_down = pcd_combined.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.005)
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("merged_point_cloud.ply", pcd_combined_down)
print("Merged point cloud saved as merged_point_cloud.ply")

ply_files = [
    "/content/test_0.ply",
    "/content/test_1.ply",
    # Add more point cloud files as needed
]

merge_point_clouds(ply_files)

The Issue:
The above code seems to transform and merge the second point cloud onto the first point cloud without properly aligning them. As a result, the merged point cloud does not accurately represent the whole sandpile.
What I Need:
I am looking for suggestions on how to correctly merge these two point clouds using Python. Ideally, the final point cloud should represent the complete sandpile accurately, with proper alignment of the two parts.
Additional Information:
The point cloud files are in .ply format.
I am using the open3d library for point cloud processing.
The alignment is expected to be done using the ICP algorithm or any other suitable method that ensures proper merging of the point clouds.
I appreciate any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue and achieve the desired point cloud merging.

ICP does not guarantee to properly align point clouds. It can easily fall into a local minima. One way to mitigate that is to start different initial starting rotation/translation and then start the ICP algorithm. You can then pick up the best match. You can also consider using other image matching algorithms.
